# Disposing objects in CDI

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

I was wondering if CDI had some way to dispose/close objects other than `@Disposes` methods?

For simple cases, I would like to do something like:

```
class MyObject {

    @Inject MyObject(MyDependencies...) {...}

    @Disposes void close() {...}
}
```

rather than having to create a `@Disposes` method elsewhere just to call `close()` like this:

```
class MyObjectManager {

    void closeMyObject(@Disposes MyObject myObject) {
        myObject.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a producer method to create instances of `MyObject` or is the class annotated properly?

Comment: No and that's another problem: a `@Disposes` must have a corresponding `@Produces`. In my case, an `@Inject`'ed constructor is enough but then, I can't have a `@Disposes` somewhere else and I can't have a `@Closes` (or similar) method on my bean that will be automatically called by CDI when it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [`@PreDestroy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PreDestroy.html).  This method gets called when whatever context the object is tied to is closed.  Annotate a method with this and that method will be invoked whenever the object is meant to be destroyed.

Comment: The only _drawback_ (if can be called so) is that method MUST NOT throw a checked exceptions, as javadoc says.

Comment: @datakey that is true of pretty much every container callback/lifecycle event, not specific to this use case.

Comment: @JohnAment yes and no. I think that if javadoc says clear a *must not*, containers should follow the rules. But certainly, (and AFAIK) CDI containers does what they want: OpenWebBeans complains about `throws`, while Weld does not.